# Calling Boost from Ruby via SWIG?

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

Suppose I want to call one or more boost library functions from Ruby code. There are many examples of times where I'd want to do this, but most recently I want to use the Boost Graph library for efficient graph processing. I think the way most often suggested for doing this is to use SWIG. Has anyone gone through and generated SWIG wrappers for the Boost library? Is this in fact the best way to interoperate with Boost? What parts of Boost cannot be accessed through SWIG because they require unsupported C++ features to work?

Comment: I am also thinking of accessing Boost Graph library from Ruby. Have you tried on it? If so, it would be of help if you can give me information about it.

Comment: Where did you end up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I have generated wrappers for the Boost libraries specifically, but I have done so for my own templated classes.

This is perfectly doable as long as you keep in mind that SWIG will wrap specific template instantiations using the [`%template`](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGPlus.html#SWIGPlus_nn30) directive.

As stated in the documentation linked above:

> [...] a bare C++ template does not define any sort of runnable object-code for which SWIG can normally create a wrapper. Therefore, in order to wrap a template, you need to give SWIG information about a particular template instantiation (e.g., `vector<int>`, `array<double>`, etc.). Second, an instantiation name such as `vector<int>` is generally not a valid identifier name in most target languages. Thus, you will need to give the template instantiation a more suitable name such as `intvector` when creating a wrapper.

With the directive your `intvector` would look something like this:

```
%template(intvector) vector<int>;
```